# system monitor showing 25 ghz cpu speed, could that have any bad effect?

Tags: cpu

[image]

I have a water cooled system, but.... I don't have that kind of wallet to be able to pull that out.

Is anyone of you that had this problem?

what I want to know is if there could be any issue relate to this bug.
you know, something like  the computer asking the CPU to give more that it can actually do and make the computer freeze or something like it.

Everything I found about something similar issue. was always about people reading lower reading.
so I told myself  maybe it is the same issue and the only one complaining are the one who see lower reading. (like if it was a bank account balance reading ^^)

Anyway,
thanks if you can light me on this issue.

system is a new build
evga ftw z87
1000 psu 
core i7 devil canyon at 4ghz  stock  (not overclocked at this speed) 
running under 30 degree cel when no load.

there is cpu-z info if it may help.

```
CPU-Z    

Binaries     
CPU-Z version   1.70.0.x64

Processors   
Number of processors    1
Number of threads   8

APICs    
Processor 0 
     -- Core 0  
         -- Thread 0    0
         -- Thread 1    1
     -- Core 1  
         -- Thread 0    2
         -- Thread 1    3
     -- Core 2  
         -- Thread 0    4
         -- Thread 1    5
     -- Core 3  
         -- Thread 0    6
         -- Thread 1    7

Timers   
     ACPI timer 3.580 MHz
     HPET timer 14.318 MHz
     Perf timer 3.897 MHz
     Sys timer  1.000 KHz


Processors Information   
Processor 1 ID = 0
     Number of cores    4 (max 8)
     Number of threads  8 (max 16)
     Name   Intel Core i7 4790K
     Codename   Haswell
     Specification  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
     Package (platform ID)  Socket 1150 LGA (0x1)
     CPUID  6.C.3
     Extended CPUID 6.3C
     Core Stepping  C0
     Technology 22 nm
     TDP Limit  88 Watts
     Tjmax  100.0 °C
     Core Speed 3994.8 MHz
     Multiplier x Bus Speed 40.0 x 99.9 MHz
     Stock frequency    4000 MHz
     Instructions sets  MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX, AVX2, FMA3
     L1 Data cache  4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
     L1 Instruction cache   4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
     L2 cache   4 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
     L3 cache   8 MBytes, 16-way set associative, 64-byte line size
     FID/VID Control    yes


     Turbo Mode supported, enabled
     Max non-turbo ratio    40x
     Max turbo ratio    40x
     Max efficiency ratio   8x
     O/C bins   unlimited
     Ratio 1 core   40x
     Ratio 2 cores  40x
     Ratio 3 cores  40x
     Ratio 4 cores  40x
     TSC    3996.1 MHz
     APERF  3991.3 MHz
     MPERF  3991.1 MHz
     IA Voltage Mode    PCU adaptive
     IA Voltage Offset  0 mV
     GT Voltage Mode    PCU adaptive
     GT Voltage Offset  0 mV
     LLC/Ring Voltage Mode  PCU adaptive
     LLC/Ring Voltage Offset    0 mV
     Agent Voltage Mode PCU adaptive
     Agent Voltage Offset   1 mV



Chipset  
Northbridge Intel Haswell rev. 06
Southbridge Intel Z97 rev. 00
Graphic Interface   PCI-Express
PCI-E Link Width    x16
PCI-E Max Link Width    x16
Memory Type DDR3
Memory Size 16 GBytes
Channels    Dual
Memory Frequency    665.8 MHz (1:5)
CAS# latency (CL)   9.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD)   9
RAS# Precharge (tRP)    9
Cycle Time (tRAS)   24
Row Refresh Cycle Time (tRFC)   200
Command Rate (CR)   1T
Uncore Frequency    3894.9 MHz

Memory SPD   
DIMM #  1
     SMBus address  0x51
     Memory type    DDR3
     Module format  UDIMM
     Manufacturer (ID)  Team Group Inc. (7F7F7F7FEF0000000000)
     Size   8192 MBytes
     Max bandwidth  PC3-10700 (667 MHz)
     Part number    Xtreem-LV-2400
     Manufacturing date Week 50/Year 13
     Number of banks    8
     Nominal Voltage    1.50 Volts
     EPP    no
     XMP    yes
     XMP revision   1.3
     AMP    no
JEDEC timings table CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
     JEDEC #1   5.0-5-5-14-19 @ 380 MHz
     JEDEC #2   6.0-6-6-17-23 @ 457 MHz
     JEDEC #3   7.0-7-7-20-27 @ 533 MHz
     JEDEC #4   8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 609 MHz
     JEDEC #5   9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 666 MHz
XMP profile XMP-2400
     Specification  PC3-19200
     Voltage level  1.650 Volts
     Min Cycle time 0.833 ns (1200 MHz)
     Max CL 10.0
     Min tRP    10.00 ns
     Min tRCD   10.00 ns
     Min tWR    15.00 ns
     Min tRAS   25.83 ns
     Min tRC    35.83 ns
     Min tRFC   261.08 ns
     Min tRTP   7.58 ns
     Min tRRD   7.50 ns
     Command Rate   2T
XMP timings table   CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC-CR @ frequency (voltage)
     XMP #1 5.0-6-6-16-22-2T @ 600 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #2 6.0-8-8-19-26-2T @ 719 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #3 7.0-9-9-22-31-2T @ 839 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #4 8.0-10-10-25-35-2T @ 959 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #5 9.0-11-11-28-39-2T @ 1080 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #6 10.0-12-12-31-44-2T @ 1200 MHz (1.650 Volts)

DIMM #  2
     SMBus address  0x53
     Memory type    DDR3
     Module format  UDIMM
     Manufacturer (ID)  Team Group Inc. (7F7F7F7FEF0000000000)
     Size   8192 MBytes
     Max bandwidth  PC3-10700 (667 MHz)
     Part number    Xtreem-LV-2400
     Manufacturing date Week 50/Year 13
     Number of banks    8
     Nominal Voltage    1.50 Volts
     EPP    no
     XMP    yes
     XMP revision   1.3
     AMP    no
JEDEC timings table CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
     JEDEC #1   5.0-5-5-14-19 @ 380 MHz
     JEDEC #2   6.0-6-6-17-23 @ 457 MHz
     JEDEC #3   7.0-7-7-20-27 @ 533 MHz
     JEDEC #4   8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 609 MHz
     JEDEC #5   9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 666 MHz
XMP profile XMP-2400
     Specification  PC3-19200
     Voltage level  1.650 Volts
     Min Cycle time 0.833 ns (1200 MHz)
     Max CL 10.0
     Min tRP    10.00 ns
     Min tRCD   10.00 ns
     Min tWR    15.00 ns
     Min tRAS   25.83 ns
     Min tRC    35.83 ns
     Min tRFC   261.08 ns
     Min tRTP   7.58 ns
     Min tRRD   7.50 ns
     Command Rate   2T
XMP timings table   CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC-CR @ frequency (voltage)
     XMP #1 5.0-6-6-16-22-2T @ 600 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #2 6.0-8-8-19-26-2T @ 719 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #3 7.0-9-9-22-31-2T @ 839 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #4 8.0-10-10-25-35-2T @ 959 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #5 9.0-11-11-28-39-2T @ 1080 MHz (1.650 Volts)
     XMP #6 10.0-12-12-31-44-2T @ 1200 MHz (1.650 Volts)


Monitoring   
Mainboard Model 142-HR-E977 (0x00000277 - 0x09AB58F0)

LPCIO    
LPCIO Vendor    Fintek
LPCIO Model F71889A
LPCIO Vendor ID 0x1934
LPCIO Chip ID   0x1005

Hardware Monitors    
Hardware monitor    Fintek F71889A
     Voltage 0  3.38 Volts [0xD3] (+3.3V)
     Voltage 1  1.79 Volts [0x60] (CPU VIN)
     Voltage 2  1.49 Volts [0x7F] (DRAM)
     Voltage 3  5.09 Volts [0x79] (VCC)
     Voltage 4  1.04 Volts [0x82] (PCH 1.05V)
     Voltage 5  1.48 Volts [0x7E] (PCH 1.5V)
     Voltage 6  11.96 Volts [0xA2] (+12V)
     Voltage 7  3.41 Volts [0xD5] (VSB3V)
     Voltage 8  3.38 Volts [0xD3] (VBAT)
     Temperature 0  27°C (80°F) [0x1B] (CPU)
     Temperature 1  31°C (87°F) [0x1F] (VREG)
     Temperature 2  28°C (82°F) [0x1C] (System)
     Fan 0  1463 RPM [0x401] (JCPU)
     Fan 1  1365 RPM [0x44B] (JPWR)
     Fan PWM 0  60 pc [0x99] (CPU)
     Fan PWM 1  60 pc [0x99] (System Fan 1)
     Fan PWM 2  40 pc [0x66] (System Fan 2)

Hardware monitor    Nuvoton NCT7802
     Voltage 0  1.70 Volts [0x352] (VIN0)
     Voltage 1  0.31 Volts [0x99] (VIN1)
     Voltage 2  0.04 Volts [0x13] (VIN2)
     Voltage 3  0.14 Volts [0x46] (VIN3)
     Voltage 4  0.12 Volts [0x3D] (VIN4)

Hardware monitor    ACPI
     Temperature 0  28°C (82°F) [0xBC2] (TZ00)
     Temperature 1  30°C (85°F) [0xBD6] (TZ01)

Hardware monitor    NVIDIA NVAPI
     Voltage 0  0.98 Volts [0x3CF] (VIN0)
     Temperature 0  45°C (113°F) [0x2D] (TMPIN0)
     Fan 0  1260 RPM [0x4EC] (FANIN0)
     Fan PWM 0  33 pc [0x21] (FANPWMIN0)


PCI Devices  
Description Host Bridge
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 0 (0x00), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x0C00
     Revision ID    0x06

Description PCI to PCI Bridge
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 1 (0x01), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x0C01
     Revision ID    0x06

Description USB Controller
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 20 (0x14), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CB1
     Revision ID    0x00

Description Communication Device
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 22 (0x16), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CBA
     Revision ID    0x00

Description Ethernet Controller
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 25 (0x19), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x153A
     Revision ID    0x00

Description USB 2.0 Controller (EHCI)
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 26 (0x1A), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CAD
     Revision ID    0x00

Description Multimedia device
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 27 (0x1B), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CA0
     Revision ID    0x00

Description PCI to PCI Bridge
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 28 (0x1C), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8C90
     Revision ID    0xD0

Description PCI to PCI Bridge
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 28 (0x1C), function 3 (0x03)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8C96
     Revision ID    0xD0

Description USB 2.0 Controller (EHCI)
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 29 (0x1D), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CA6
     Revision ID    0x00

Description PCI to ISA Bridge
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 31 (0x1F), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CC4
     Revision ID    0x00

Description Serial ATA Controller
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 31 (0x1F), function 2 (0x02)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8C82
     Revision ID    0x00

Description SMBus Controller
Location    bus 0 (0x00), device 31 (0x1F), function 3 (0x03)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x8086
     Model ID   0x8CA2
     Revision ID    0x00

Description VGA Controller
Location    bus 1 (0x01), device 0 (0x00), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x10DE
     Model ID   0x11C0
     Revision ID    0xA1

Description Multimedia device
Location    bus 1 (0x01), device 0 (0x00), function 1 (0x01)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x10DE
     Model ID   0x0E0B
     Revision ID    0xA1

Description Serial ATA Controller
Location    bus 3 (0x03), device 0 (0x00), function 0 (0x00)
Common header   
     Vendor ID  0x1B4B
     Model ID   0x9220
     Revision ID    0x10


DMI  
DMI BIOS    
     vendor American Megatrends Inc.
     version    4.6.5
     date   07/29/2014
     ROM size   4096 KB

DMI System Information  
     manufacturer   EVGA INTERNATIONAL CO.LTD
     product    To be filled by O.E.M.
     version    To be filled by O.E.M.
     serial To be filled by O.E.M.
     UUID   {03000200-0400-0500-0006-000700080009}
     SKU    To be filled by O.E.M.
     family To be filled by O.E.M.

DMI Baseboard   
     vendor EVGA INTERNATIONAL CO.LTD
     model  142-HR-E977
     revision   1.0
     serial To be filled by O.E.M.

DMI System Enclosure    
     manufacturer   To Be Filled By O.E.M.
     chassis type   Desktop
     chassis serial To Be Filled By O.E.M.

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J1A1 (internal)
     designation    PS2Mouse (external)
     port type  Mouse Port
     connector  PS/2

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J1A1 (internal)
     designation    Keyboard (external)
     port type  Keyboard Port
     connector  PS/2

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J2A1 (internal)
     designation    TV Out (external)
     connector  Mini Centronics Type-14

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J2A2A (internal)
     designation    COM A (external)
     port type  Serial Port 16550A
     connector  DB-9 male

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J2A2B (internal)
     designation    Video (external)
     port type  Video Port
     connector  DB-15 female

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J3A1 (internal)
     designation    USB1 (external)
     port type  USB
     connector  Access Bus (USB)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J3A1 (internal)
     designation    USB2 (external)
     port type  USB
     connector  Access Bus (USB)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J3A1 (internal)
     designation    USB3 (external)
     port type  USB
     connector  Access Bus (USB)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9A1 - TPM HDR (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9C1 - PCIE DOCKING CONN (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J2B3 - CPU FAN (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J6C2 - EXT HDMI (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J3C1 - GMCH FAN (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J1D1 - ITP (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9E2 - MDC INTPSR (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9E4 - MDC INTPSR (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9E3 - LPC HOT DOCKING (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9E1 - SCAN MATRIX (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J9G1 - LPC SIDE BAND (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J8F1 - UNIFIED (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J6F1 - LVDS (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J2F1 - LAI FAN (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J2G1 - GFX VID (internal)

DMI Port Connector  
     designation    J1G6 - AC JACK (internal)

DMI Extension Slot  
     designation    J6B2
     type   A5
     populated  yes

DMI Extension Slot  
     designation    J6B1
     type   A5
     populated  yes

DMI Extension Slot  
     designation    J6D1
     type   A5
     populated  yes

DMI Extension Slot  
     designation    J7B1
     type   A5
     populated  yes

DMI Extension Slot  
     designation    J8B4
     type   A5
     populated  yes

DMI OEM Strings 
     string[0]  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

DMI Processor   
     manufacturer   Intel
     model  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
     clock speed    4000.0 MHz
     FSB speed  100.0 MHz
     multiplier 40.0x

DMI Physical Memory Array   
     location   Motherboard
     usage  System Memory
     correction None
     max capacity   32768 MBytes
     max# of devices    4

DMI Memory Device   
     designation    ChannelA-DIMM0
     format DIMM
     type   unknown

DMI Memory Device   
     designation    ChannelA-DIMM1
     format DIMM
     type   unknown
     total width    64 bits
     data width 64 bits
     size   8192 MBytes

DMI Memory Device   
     designation    ChannelB-DIMM0
     format DIMM
     type   unknown

DMI Memory Device   
     designation    ChannelB-DIMM1
     format DIMM
     type   unknown
     total width    64 bits
     data width 64 bits
     size   8192 MBytes


Graphics     
Number of adapters  1

Graphic APIs     
API NVIDIA I/O
API NVIDIA NVAPI

Display Adapters     
Display adapter 0   
     Name   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660
     Board Manufacturer EVGA Corp.
     Revision   A1
     Memory size    2 GB
     PCI device bus 1 (0x1), device 0 (0x0), function 0 (0x0)
     Vendor ID  0x10DE (0x3842)
     Model ID   0x11C0 (0x2662)
     Performance Level  2D Desktop
         Core clock 324.0 MHz
         Memory clock   324.0 MHz
     Performance Level  Default
         Core clock 324.0 MHz
         Memory clock   810.0 MHz
     Performance Level  3D Applications
         Core clock 549.0 MHz
         Memory clock   3004.0 MHz
     Performance Level  3D Applications
         Core clock 549.0 MHz
         Memory clock   3004.0 MHz

Win32_VideoController   AdapterRAM = 0x80000000 (2147483648)
Win32_VideoController   DriverVersion = 9.18.13.4052
Win32_VideoController   DriverDate = 07/02/2014

Software     
Windows Version Microsoft Windows 8.1 (6.3) 64-bit (Build 9600)
DirectX Version 11.0
```

Comment: It's good that you included a lot of detail about your system/specs, but that's almost never necessary. This is likely just a software bug. I see one of two things happening: your CPU runs at a normal clock speed and nothing bad happens, or your CPU is from a future Earth where CPUs are crafted from platinum, so you're ticking at 25 gHz and your CPU wouldn't melt anyway. The clock can't ever tick that fast - there is a real physical limit, regardless of what monitoring tools might show as the 'current' clock rate.

Comment: lol thanks, the actual running speed of the processor is aroud 4 ghz, the only things that I was wondering if it could eventually cause some problem. like   if I put a 40 feet fiftweel(R_V)  behind a ford fiesta  because someone write the wrong number on the spec sheet on  towing ability...  il you understand what I mean by that.   for now I will not bother with it ^^

Comment: Well you said that it was under 30C when no load, and the 'danger zone' is around 80C for Intel chips, so you should be all right especially if you have water cooling. That is an interesting reading from CPU-Z though; I can't explain that.

Comment: The number separator doesn't look normal... it's showing a comma instead of a dot.... the numbers are a different story, but then it may be related... is it anything to do with system locale/region settings?